# Problem in windows mode @neutralinojs/neu@3.0.2

Tags: neutralinojs

- i want  create a simple application using Neutralinojs.
- go to section Your First Neutralinojs App and Creating a new app
- but after `neu run` in command
  windows open and not show anything?

image from my desktop

[image]

---

app in browse mode and cloud is correct and successful run!

Answer (score 1):

this issue cause by windows.

run this command with administrator privileges. this should fix your issues

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy"
```

ref:
[v2-specification](https://github.com/neutralinojs/v2-specification/blob/main/webview.md)